# Needing help to improve some TSQL "not exists" query performance

Tags: t-sql, query-performance

I'm having an performance issue running a query on a table containing 750 000 entries. It takes between 15 to 20 seconds to execute, blocking access to the database during that time and creating lots of error logs (and angry customers, of course).

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @FROM_ID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'XXX'
DECLARE @TO_ID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'YYY'

update tbl_share
set user_id = @TO_ID 
where user_id = @FROM_ID
and not exists (
    select *
    from tbl_share ts
    where ts.file_id = file_id
    and ts.user_id = @TO_ID
    and ts.corr_id = corr_id
    and ts.local_group_id = local_group_id
    and ts.global_group_id = global_group_id 
)
```

I'm kind of stuck right now since my TSQL knowledge is limited.
I'm wondering if:

- I should create a temporary table
- I should select something else than "*"

I haven't lot of opportunities to run the tests since it's a production database and there are permanently 10-20 customers connected on day time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This seems to be useless: `and ts.corr_id = corr_id
    and ts.local_group_id = local_group_id
    and ts.global_group_id = global_group_id `

Comment: @RBarryYoung oh, thx, I'll revise my mythology

Comment: Another approach to improve the performance is probably by using a Common Table Expression (CTE).
@Tim Schmelter: Yes it does.

Comment: @sjkm: "Yes it does" means, yes it is useless? The whole condition makes no sense since you need to use the  first table, e.g.: `where ts.file_id = tbl_share.file_id` instead of `ts.file_id = file_id` which is always true.

Comment: No I think the same ;)

Comment: You should fix the bug discussed above before worrying about performance. i presume you intended this to be correlated. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c610/1). If you still have performance problems after that post the `CREATE TABLE` including indexes and the execution plan.

Comment: @ALL: the constraint is necessary to prevent the query to insert double lines with exact matching primary keys. Every field in the sub-query are primary foreign keys. I should have be more specific on that question, my bad.

Comment: @BorisDelormas - `where ts.file_id = file_id and ts.corr_id = corr_id and ts.local_group_id = local_group_id and ts.global_group_id = global_group_id` is just comparing the same column values to themselves.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I thought it was comparing values from the subquery with thoses from the main query

Comment: @BorisDelormas - no it isn't. It is comparing values from the subquery with themselves. A non qualified column name is resolved from the closest scope outwards. The SQL Fiddle link I posted earlier fixes that particular issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith: when running your SQL Fiddle without being specific (check [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c610/2](here)), the execution plan says it's scanning both tables ts and ts1 whereas I didn't precise ts in the query

Answer (score 0):

How about restructuring your code logic?

```
DECLARE @FROM_ID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'XXX'
DECLARE @TO_ID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'YYY'

IF NOT EXISTS (select *
    from tbl_share ts
    where ts.user_id = @TO_ID)
BEGIN

    update tbl_share
    set user_id = @TO_ID 
    where user_id = @FROM_ID

END
```

So, you are doing your check beforehand and do only updating the database in the case it is needed.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the approach but I can't since I have to keep the constraints

    **ts.corr_id = corr_id
    and ts.local_group_id = local_group_id
    and ts.global_group_id = global_group_id**

Comment: OK, I think then you are missing some indices e.g. one over all the columns contained in the NOT EXISTS statement.

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TBL_SHARE_EXISTS] ON [TBL_SHARE](file_id, user_id, corr_id, local_group_id, global_group_id) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with optimizing the select.
Check query plans.
If that is the PK then is it fragmented?

```
select * 
from tbl_share
where user_id = @FROM_ID
and not exists (
    select *
    from tbl_share ts
    where ts.file_id = file_id
    and ts.user_id = @TO_ID
    and ts.corr_id = corr_id
    and ts.local_group_id = local_group_id
    and ts.global_group_id = global_group_id 
    )

select tUpdate.* 
from tbl_share as tUpdate
left outer join tbl_share as tExists 
  on tUpdate.user_id = @FROM_ID
 and tExists.user_id = @TO_ID
 and tExists.file_id = tUpdate.file_id
 and tExists.corr_id = tUpdate.corr_id
 and tExists.local_group_id = tUpdate.local_group_id
 and tExists.global_group_id = tUpdate.global_group_id 
where tExists.user_id is null
```